# ASP.NET Core 6: Authentication via Azure AD and local user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm creating a POC where the user can authenticate himself via Azure AD.

It works perfectly but now I want to persist in a local database the user information (not the login/password) if is not already present.

So I need to find the right 'point' in the flow where, after a successfully authentication, the system checks if the user already exists, if not then it saves it.

Which is the best point?

I see 2 techniques:

- On the login button pass a redirect url that the Microsoft server will redirect user to at the finish of the authentication flow. I don't like this way because seems too weak for me.

  ```
  <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" asp-route-redirecturi='/Home/profile'>Sign in</a>
  ```
- Customize the options in **AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp** to react to the event **OnTicketReceived**. I don't fully understand this event: I can't get if it is raised only once after the user authentication or also every time that the Authentication Token is refreshed.

  ```
  builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

            options.Events.OnTicketReceived += async context =>
            {
                //Get the full user's profile from Azure
                var azureService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAzureService>();
                var principal = await azureService.GetProfileAsync(context.Principal).ConfigureAwait(false);

                //Then persist it into the Application Database
                var userService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUserService>();
                await userService.PersistAsync(principal).ConfigureAwait(false);

            };
        })
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] { "user.read" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
  ```

Thank you!

Comment: What challenges you are getting here? How do you decide when to authenticate either in `auzre ad` or in `local user`?  Where are you taking this decision?

Comment: In this scenario I don't have other authentication system except for the Azure AD.
The 'problem' that I need to solve is that I need to persist a 'user' entity with some metadata as soon as possible after the very first user login. 
In this user entity I will persist metadata not present into the A.D. (and a custom/app role base system). Thank you for your time.

Comment: But do you have the same user local and azure ad as well? Or they are diffrent? Could you share currently where you have blocking or having issue with?

Comment: Sorry for the delay and tnx for the interest. The Azure Ad Account contains personal info + username and password. I need to have a "User" in my app for each Azure AD Account for other extra application info like timezone, language preference, or simply have an entry in database to use as reference in other tables. It is so strange?

Comment: did you figure this out @IGionny ?